# Survey 123 date calculation

Tags: arcgis-survey123

I want to create a formula in Survey 123 that take date from date field "date_"
I want to put 15 as day,month I want to put next month (Example if January the month will be February, and the year will be the same

What is wrong in this formula?

```
15, month(${date_}) + 1, year(${date_})
```

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why you think the formula is wrong.  Presumably there is some error message, unexpected behaviour, or other reason which you could elaborate on.  I presume that you have entered that formula into the 'Calculation' field on one of the Survey123 question rows in the XMLForm spreadsheet.  However, you should make this clear in your question.  Please edit your question to include any new information that you can provide.